# Implicit call of a base metaclass init function in Python 3

Tags: python, metaprogramming, metaclass

Having a code below:

```
class BaseMeta(type):
    def __init__(self, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict):
        super(BaseMeta, self).__init__(cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict)
        print("BaseMeta init")
        print(cls_dict)

class Proxy():
    class __metaclass__(BaseMeta, type):
        def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict):
            return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict)

        def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
            print("Proxy init")
            BaseMeta.__init__(cls, name, bases, dict)

class Service(Proxy):
    def some_endpoint(self, a):
        print(a)
```

When running in Python 2, output would be similar to:

```
Proxy init
BaseMeta init
{'__module__': '__main__', '__metaclass__': <class '__main__.__metaclass__'>}
Proxy init
BaseMeta init
{'some_endpoint': <function some_endpoint at 0x8011e35d0>, '__module__': '__main__'}
```

BaseMeta init is called implicitly on a script init (twice_

In python 3, nothing will be printed at all. Assuming you can't change **BaseMeta** and **Service** classes, how would you modify **Proxy** class so you can see the output similar to output above in Python 3? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probem is that `__metclass__` no longer has any special status in Python 3. Normally, you specify the metaclass like an argument in the class definition statement:

```
class Foo(metaclass=FooMeta):
    ...
```

You can do something like this:

```
class BaseMeta(type):
    def __init__(self, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict):
        super(BaseMeta, self).__init__(cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict)
        print("BaseMeta init")
        print(cls_dict)

class ProxyMeta(BaseMeta):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict)
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        print("Proxy init")
        BaseMeta.__init__(cls, name, bases, dict)

class Proxy(metaclass=ProxyMeta):
    pass

class Service(Proxy):
    def some_endpoint(self, a):
        print(a)
```